# How to create a specific wine version and a new prefix

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I want to create a second wine prefix 32-bit and I want a specific wine version for example 1.4

I have wine installed with the official ppa

So can I create second wine prefix with specific wine version if yes, how ?

Comment: Any wine version can open a prefix, you can't force a version to a prefix. Architecture, Windows version, etc. can be done.

Comment: I think I can if I compile wine but I do not want to do so

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Compile, don't compile, doesn't make a difference. The wineprefix does have information as to which version used it last, but you can't make it so that only a specific version of wine can use a prefix. When you need to, you just do: `WINEPREFIX=/foo/bar wine-x.y ...`.

Comment: `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.testwine wine-1.7.30`
Something like this ?? if yes sadly it did not work.

Comment: Define "did not work".

Comment: Sorry `wine-1.7.30: command not found`

Comment: Well, if you installed from the repositories, there are no versioned binaries of Wine. You will have to compile from source.

Comment: No I used the ppa guess I have to compile. Thank you for help

Comment: It always was my understanding that this is one of the use cases for **playonlinux** (if hard disk space does not matter).